# Reading pathvalue from file, appending string overwriting the variable in shell linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, append

My Input file: `env.properties`

```
JAVA_HOME=/home/Desktop/jdk1.7.0_67
```

Shell Code:

```
ENVPROPERTIES=env.properties
JAVA_HOME=$(awk -F '[ ="]+' '$1=="JAVA_HOME"{printf $2}' $ENVPROPERTIES)
echo $JAVA_HOME/bin
```

->Will give outout: `/bine/Desktop/jdk1.7.0_67`

Even Tried reading with while loop::

```
set -f; IFS==
while read a b line
do
    echo $a/bin
    echo $b/bin
done < $ENVPROPERTIES
set =f; unset IFS
```

Will give output::

```
JAVA_HOME/bin
/bine/Desktop/jdk1.7.0_67
```

Some how, it is overwriting variable for Path but working with other values like `JAVA_HOME.`

Comment: Both of these work for me. In your case the first three/four letters or /home are replace by /bin. You can try using cut to simplify the first approach `JAVA_HOME=$(grep "JAVA_HOME=" $ENVPROPERTIES | cut -f2 -d"=")`

Comment: @rahul Obviously CR is the culprit here.

Comment: @parthmanvar You're welcome. You can accept my answer (check mark below the arrow buttons) if you deem the problem as solved. Or feel free to pursue if it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple. Your `env.properties` file is a DOS file with CRLF as newline, so you are picking up a carriage return in `JAVA_HOME`. Try `dos2unix` on the input file, or manually edit it so that it's using LF as newline.